# How do I get my google-site-verification TXT record for domain verification if I'm not a GSuite admin?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to add the appropriate google-site-verification TXT record, in order to do domain verification for an OAuth consent screen (e.g. [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit)) that I want to set up for my Google Cloud service.  Unfortunately, the documentation for doing that points me to ([this](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#authorized-domains)) doc, which eventually leads me to a help doc like [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7173990?hl=en&ref_topic=4487622).  That help doc seems to assume that I am a GSuite admin.  What if I'm **not a GSuite admin** and **not even a GSuite user** and want to set up domain verification for a host that I own?  Where can I obtain the appropriate google-site-verification TXT record that I need for use with the Google Cloud Platform?

Thanks in advance.

-Mark

Answer (score 3):

Your domain needs to be an Authorized Domain to be able to use it with OAuth 2.0. To authorize it (and in turn get your google-site-verification TXT record), you can add the domain to Google Search Console.

1. Go to https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome.
2. Enter your domain name under the Domain option, and click on Continue.
3. It will then check for verification of the domain (and when it fails), it will give you a 'google-site-verification' TXT record. Add this to your domain's DNS zone and then click on Verify.

Do note, that depending on DNS propagation, this can take minutes to days to complete. More often than not, it will have propagated within hours.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher, but my question is how do I authorize my domain without being a GSuite admin?  Not every domain is used as a GSuite domain.

Comment: Christopher, I don't see how one creates a GSuite account and become a GSuite admin without actually buying a GSuite subscription.

Comment: I've amended my answer to use a different method. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Chistopher, do you know if that method of authentication works for the OAuth domain verification?  Do you have a reference indicating that it does?

Comment: I can’t guarantee that it does, as I’ve got a GSuite subscription and I follow guides as recommended by Google. You will need to try it, as Google wont have an article confirming the method I found will work.